# android version Code android version name cordova

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-cmd

After changes to my code i trying to update my android application version build with cordova.
In AndroidManifest.xml i changes the android:versionName to higher number like "1.2.9" to "1.2.10" also and the android:versionCode at same file.
after build using cordova these two numbers change automatically. i tried to add the android:versionName at config.xml file but after cordova build the same thing is happening and during the build i am getting error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the version-code and version-name for android you have to add `android-versionCode=""` and `version=""` to the `<widget>` tag in `config.xml` as following example shows:

```
<widget android-versionCode="100" version="1.0.0" ... >
```

You should never modify anything in the `platforms` folder directly as it get recreated when you prepare/build/readd the platform.

Comment: by adding android-versionCode="100" version="1.0.0" now the android:versionName="1.2.10" is ok but  android:versionCode="" change again automatically in a number smaller number than the previous version and that is problem for upload app in google play. I added the above code you wrote in folders /cordova/config.xml   /cordova.js/config.xml  and /cordova/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml in which of these folders is the right one?

Comment: by adding xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in widget at config.xml solved the error but the problem with  android:versionCode that change the number i add after build is still there, any idea about that?

Comment: Do **NOT** modify _anything_ in the `platforms/android` folder, it is generated when you run a build and will alwaxs be reset. You have to modify the `config.xml` in `<your-project-root/src/config.xml`.